# Code running but giving error when knit in r

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

This code runs alright when we run chunks code in markdown.

````
```{r , echo = FALSE, results='asis', comment=NA, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
library(plyr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
comp.name <- readline(prompt = "Enter the company name: ")
tyu2 <- getSymbols(comp.name , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE, from = "2018-03-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
tyu2 <- as.data.frame(tyu2)
tyu <- tyu2[,6]
x <- row.names(tyu2)
final <- length(tyu)
final <- as.numeric(final)
p <- ggplot(data = tyu2 , aes(x= x ,y=tyu))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
p
```
````

But when try to knit with markdown, it gives error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(tyu2, , 6) : undefined columns selected
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> [.data.frame
```

What does this error mean. How to resolve. Please help. Found answers online that install all packages. Have everything installed.

Comment: no, there are 6 columns, but even if i change the 6 to 1, still the same error is shown. The data downloads fine. This runs properly if just run with Control+Enter. But i need to knit the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a line for user input. However, knitr will jump to the next line assuming the user didn't input anything. This means `comp.name` will be `""` and `getSymbols()` retrieves empty data, meaning all columns are technically undefined.

I would suggest the following change:

````
```{r , echo = FALSE, results='asis', comment=NA, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)
library(plyr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
comp.name <- readline(prompt = "Enter the company name: ")
# For case user inpt is empty
if (comp.name == "") {
  comp.name <- "AAPL"
}
tyu2 <- getSymbols(comp.name , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE, from = "2018-03-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
tyu2 <- as.data.frame(tyu2)
tyu <- tyu2[,6]
x <- row.names(tyu2)
final <- length(tyu)
final <- as.numeric(final)
p <- ggplot(data = tyu2 , aes(x= x ,y=tyu))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
p
```
````

I was able to knit this just fine.

Comment: But wont't it then always show apple database. What if i want to make it user-friendly?

Comment: It will only show the results for APPL if nothing was entered by the user. You can also think about writing a `warning()`, such as "no data was entered. Falling back to display results for 'APPL'". On a broader point: why do you want to knit this in the first place? If you expect user input, then a knitr script seems to be the wrong place, since it is impossible to receive input while it runs...

Comment: Yes, i got what i was doing was wrong. Using the shiny app to make it more interactive is better

Comment: I think a shiny app would be a good way to move forward! I learned shiny with some video tutorial. I think it was this one: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/ If you do not have any more questions regarding this, please consider accepting my answer, to close this.